# Null pointer exception: installing glassfish4 on Solaris 11.3

Tags: software-installation, solaris

I'm trying to install glassfish4 on Solaris 11.3 machine by using `glassfish-4.0-unix.sh` file.

After `sh ./glassfish-4.0-unix.sh` command the graphical installer starts. Then at JDK selection page - no JDK options to select, and it prints the error in terminal window:

```
// Error: Exception in runnable:Method Invocation theJava.getInstalledJDKDetails : at Line: 99 : in file: inline evaluation of: ``   import java.io.File;   import java.util.List;   import java.util.ArrayList;   . . . '' : theJava .getInstalledJDKDetails ( )

Called from method: run : at Line: -1 : in file: <Called from Java Code> : <Compiled Java Code>
Target exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

What could be a problem here?

[image]

Also it's not possible to enter JDK location manually. `JAVA_HOME` is set to:

```
#echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/jdk/jdk1.8.0_60
```

Java version:

```
#java -version
java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)

#pkg info jdk-8
          Name: developer/java/jdk-8
       Summary: Java Platform Standard Edition Development Kit (1.8.0_60-b27)
   Description: The Java Platform Standard Edition Development Kit (JDK)
                includes both the runtime environment (Java virtual machine, the
                Java platform classes and supporting files) and development
                tools (compilers, debuggers, tool libraries and other tools).
                The JDK is a development environment for building applications,
                applets and components that can be deployed with the Java
                Platform Standard Edition Runtime Environment.
      Category: Development/Java
         State: Installed
     Publisher: solaris
       Version: 1.8.0.60.27
 Build Release: 5.11
        Branch: None
Packaging Date: August 12, 2015 04:12:24 PM
          Size: 96.23 MB
          FMRI: pkg://solaris/developer/java/jdk-8@1.8.0.60.27,5.11:20150812T161224Z
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:

It seems the issue is actually with the installer being executed with JDK8.
the steps I did were:

```
pkg install jdk-7
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.7.0_
./glassfish-4.0-unix.sh
```

After this I was able to select the SDK.
Notice that in the release nodes for Glassfish 4.0, JDK 8 is not supported. more info [here at certification matrix](http://glassfish.java.net/docs/4.0/glassfish40cert-matrix.xls)

Comment: jdk-8 is installed..

Comment: Just noticed that glassfish4 graphical console (over http/https) has a lot of bugs recently - for example you can not enable secure admin, or create database connection pool (but on CLI everything works fine). So I've downloaded latest nightly release [here](http://download.oracle.com/glassfish/5.0/nightly/) - at least I was able to create database connection pool.